# preg_match is not matching

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to get the ID from `transaction(123456)` in the HTML

It doesn't seem to return anything.

```
 $response = "</body> </html><script type='text/javascript'>transaction(123456);</script>";

 preg_match('/^transaction\((\d+)\)/', $response, $match);

 print_r($match);

if (is_numeric($match[1])) {
  echo "Your ID: " . $match[1];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you have the start of string anchor `^`, and `transaction(` isn't at the start of the string. Remove that (or add a non-greedy match) and it'll work (as shown by [this demo](http://viper-7.com/P0cIZC)):

```
preg_match('/transaction\((\d+)\)/', $response, $match);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/^transaction\((\d+)\)/', $response, $match);
```

should be

```
preg_match('/transaction\((\d+)\)/', $response, $match);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$response = "</body> </html><script type='text/javascript'>transaction(123456);</script>";

preg_match('/transaction\((\d+)\)/', $response, $match);

print_r($match);

if (is_numeric($match[1])) {
  echo "Your ID: " . $match[1];
}
```

This is the code you want.
The reason is, that your pattern started with "^" and this character means, that you expect taht "transaction" appears in the front of your string "$response", but there is "..."